# CFLDAP failing to retrieve Integer8 attributes, ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, active-directory

I am trying to retrieve accountExpires attribute value from Active Directory using CFLDAP.
However, when I cfdrump the recordset, I get blank values for its value.

I've tried retrieving other Integer8 attribute values and they are all blank.

From this, I checked the AD using ADExplorer and they all have values in there (in date format.. ADExplorer must have auto conversion tool).

Any idea why it is not getting anything?

PS. I'm using CF5, Win2k3 on the server

Answer (score 0):

For your information, as explain in [Account-Expires attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Microsoft documentation), Account-Expires is a 64 bits value that represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC). you can find in [this blog](http://www.rlmueller.net/Integer8Attributes.htm) more information about how to exploit it.

---

Edited

You perhaps find some help [here](http://ruthsarian.wordpress.com/category/programming/).
A 64 bit integer in Java is a [java.lang.Long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) and Longs are [implicitly converted to Integer](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Java_8.html) in Coldfusion

Comment: Yes, I am aware this is an 64-bit attribute but I am unable to do use the value of this attribute if I don't first get the value from the CFLDAP. When I try to retrieve it by CFLDAP query, I get blank values. Plus, I have no idea how it can be incorporated into my CF code as your example is a VB

Answer (score 0):

It is a 64-bit value attempting to be retrieved by a 32-bit application.  CF5 isn't even Java.  Is upgrading an option?  Try the same cfldap call from a 64-bit env, say a newer workstation with cf 9 dev edition.

Comment: Yes, it looks like there is no way of doing this at this state.

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a simple web service using C# and consume the web service in CF.